# Excel VBA Redim of variables giving odd and empty values

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble with some loops in some code that I have inherited but that I can't get to run. I have passed what I assume are the correct values into the function ([see my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70715126)), but now I am struggling to have the initial loops work.

The function works fine when called in a cell. However, when it runs in this macro, it is giving me a few errors, which I have chased back to the ReDim of the Lambda and v variables.

When I check it in the debugger, Lambda has the value of 0.33, but the value of the variable Splines is 1, and there is no variable with the value 0.33 that it could be picking up nearby.
Meanwhile I would expect V to pick up the value of 2, i.e. 1+1, but instead it has the value of 0.

I cannot work out why this is happening. Here is the code.

```
Function Spline(form As String, Splines As Integer, params As Variant, knots As Variant, coef As Variant, tstar As Range) 'form is type of spline, splines is number of knots, params is gammas, knots as knot posititions, coef as 0, tstar as cycle length in days

Dim Lambda As Variant
Dim v As Variant
Dim kmin, kmax As Double
Dim vtstar As Variant
Dim vspline As Variant
Dim a As Long

vtstar = tstar.Value2 'set vtstar as second value of the array of the cycle length
ReDim vspline(1 To UBound(vtstar), 1 To 1) 'set vspline to be cycle lengths without the 0

For a = 1 To UBound(vtstar) 'for each cycle to the max cycle

    If vtstar(a, 1) = 0 Then 'for each cycle

        vspline(a, 1) = 1 'recoding the days cycles into cycle number
        'Exit Function
        GoTo Avert 'unsure of this functionality, i think its just part of the loop syntax, by the 'exit function notation

    End If

    timeS = Log(vtstar(a, 1)) 'set timeS as the log of the cycle length

    ReDim Lambda(Splines, 0) 'set lambda to number of knots
    ReDim v(Splines + 1, 0)    'recode v to number of knots plus 1

    v(0, 0) = 1
    v(1, 0) = timeS 'unsure about this part
```

This is causing errors when the lambda and v variables are used in calculations further down in the function, first causing the lambda calculations to give "subscript out of range" error when called in this loop, I assume because 0.33 isn't a cycle number:

```
For i = 1 To Splines 'loop for each variable in splines (number of knots)

    Lambda(i, 0) = (kmax - knots(i + 1)) / ulamb 'calculate lambda as kmax - knots+1 divided by difference between max and min knot values

Next i
```

(kmax, knots and ulamb appear to be calculating correctly)

And then I am getting a Error2015 error on the following loop which uses v

```
s = Application.SumProduct(params, v) 'set s as multiply gammas by v
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Really needs a complete and runnable code listing, along with sample input values so we can reproduce you problem...

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what your previous question was.
Struggle a bit with your description.

> the value of the variable Splines is 1

Is Splines a constant = 1? You do not show how Splines is a variable but you state it is equal to the number of knots...

```
ReDim Lambda(Splines, 0) 'set lambda to number of knots
```

If Splines = 1, you are re-dimensioning Lambda to an array of size 2x1. So your array will hold two values.

```
For i = 1 To Splines 'loop for each variable in splines (number of knots)

    Lambda(i, 0) = (kmax - knots(i + 1)) / ulamb 'calculate lambda as kmax - knots+1 divided by difference between max and min knot values

Next i
```

If Splines = 1 you are starting your loop at 1 and ending at 1... So your array Lambda(0, 0) is empty. You will have a value in Lambda(1, 0).

Comment: Apologies, splines is an integer, the variables are defined as ```Function Spline(form As String, Splines As Integer, params As Variant, knots As Variant, coef As Variant, tstar As Range)
'form is type of spline, splines is number of knots, params is gammas, knots as knot posititions, coef as 0, tstar as cycle length in days``` and splines are either 1 for a 1-knot spline model or 2 for a 2-knot spline model.

Comment: @SarahRoberts Can you edit the original question and add this code there?

Comment: I still get the sense you are unintentionally using an array... ReDim is to redimension an array. Perhaps you can elaborate on if/how you want to use an array?